# Wrapping embedded images with a div

Tags: media, wysiwyg

When embedding an image in CKEditor on Drupal 7 any styles or alignment are applied directly to the image itself e.g.

```
<img src="..." style="float: left; width: 90px; height: 150px" />
```

However this doesn't allow for a great deal of CSS control over the appearance for the image because the inline styles override CSS.

How can I do the following 2 things:

1. Automatically wrap the image in a div and apply classes to this instead of the img element
2. For alignment use classes (e.g. 'image-left', 'image-right' etc.) instead of inline styles

So the above example would instead be rendered as:

```
<div class="image-left">
    <img src="..." styles="width: 90px; height: 150px" />
</div>
```

Comment: That's how CKEditor works, nothing Drupal can do to help you there. If you want that sort of functionality you should probably open a feature request on CKEditor's issue queue. It's a pretty configurable library already, though, so you might be able to just get stuck in and produce that sort of functionality with their config. Not really a question for this site, Stack Overflow would probably be your best bet

Comment: I came here from Stack overflow after reading a similar question and a comment saying the questioner should come here and ask instead. I think this is a 'Would like to have' rather than a 'Must have'

Comment: CKEditor isn't made by Drupal though, it's a 3rd-party library. Questions on configuring it that don't relate to Drupal (e.g. a Drupal-specific plugin) aren't on-topic here because they're only related to the JS config inside CKEditor. Unless there's a Drupal-specific discipline involved (which it doesn't look like there is from the question), it's off-topic here I'm afraid

Comment: Look at this post [How to customize the CKEditor on your Drupal 7 Website](http://www.drupalwoo.com/content/how-customize-ckeditor-drupal-7-site) and others similar. It allows you to create custom styles for the styles dopdown, which does not do exactly as per your requirements but is a close approximation. I've used it in the past to create floated divs.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding a wrapper div, you could use !important.

```
img {
    float: left !important;
    height: 150px !important;
    width: 90px !important;
}
```

This would override the style added in CKEDITOR. You could do the same for alignment using classes, adding them directly to the image through CKEDITOR.